# How to print the row and column of a number?

Tags: c

I have an assignment that generate a 100 numbers in 10x10 table. Then sort it by bubble sort and the let the user search for a specific number. If number is in the table though it should print out which column and row it is. If the number is in the first row of the table it works perfect but if its on other rows it doesn't work as I want.

I tried to have *If* statement and printfs for every row and it worked but I am not allowed to do that and have to write down a general function for that. Can Anyone help me?

```
void siffra(int tal[100], int val){
printf("Enter the value to find:\n");
scanf("%d", &val);
int first = 0;
int last = 99;
int middle = (first+last)/2;
  while (first <= last) {
  if (tal[middle] < val)
     first = middle + 1;    
  else if (tal[middle] == val) {
     printf("%d is present at line %d column %d .\n",val,last, middle+1);
     break;
  }
  else
     last = middle - 1;
  middle = (first + last)/2;
  }
  if (first > last)
  printf("Not found! %d is not present in the list.\n", val);  
   }
```

Comment: Why is `val` an argument? It should be a local variable if you're immediately jamming a value into it without even looking at it first.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: It  might be best to step through this code in a debugger to see where it's going wrong. Normally I'd do a binary search recursively, though this approach should be valid. Spotting an off-by-one error at a glance is tricky.

Comment: How do you convert the position in `tal` to row and column?  There should be a /10 somewhere.

Comment: @stark  Thats what I am asking for. I really dont know where to put tal[]/10. And I think there should be a tal[]%10 also.

Comment: Once you find the index of the number in tal, row is `index/10`, col is `index%10`

Comment: @tadman I don't think the problem is with val as an argument. If you want the whole codes I can send it to you

Comment: That's not a bug, but it's bizarre, and to fix problems you should remove anything that's not right.